# Reactjs promise load user data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm trying to load data from my firebase after I checked if a user is signed in. I tried to do it with a promise, but I get this error

> whenAuth.then is not a function

I tried also to load the data from `componentDidMount()` and `render()` methods, but the query didn't wait for the initialisation of the user.

```
componentWillMount() {
  let whenAuth =
       firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      const userProfile = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      if(user){
        this.setState({
          authenticated: true,
          name : userProfile.displayName,
          email : userProfile.email,
          uid : userProfile.uid,
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          authenticated: false,
        })
        return <Redirect to="/"/>
      }
    })
  whenAuth.then(()=>{
      const previousCards = this.state.cards;
        firebase.database().ref().child('app').child('cards')
        .orderByChild('uid').equalTo(this.state.uid)
           .once('value', snap => {
             snap.forEach(childSnapshot => {
             previousCards.push ({
               id: childSnapshot.key,
               cardDesc: childSnapshot.val().cardDesc,
               cardPreis: childSnapshot.val().cardPreis,
               cardHeading: childSnapshot.val().cardHeading,
               cardBewertung: childSnapshot.val().bewertung,
               cardImage: childSnapshot.val().imageUrl,
               standOrt: childSnapshot.val().ort,
               imageArr: childSnapshot.val().imageArr,
             })
             this.setState ({
               cards: previousCards,
             })
           })
         })
       })

  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you sure that `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` returns a promise ?

Comment: `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` does not return a Promise: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

Comment: no it dosen't returns a promise, but i really don't know how to elsewhere execute a function after an other

Comment: [.onAuthStateChange](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) does not return a promise but it is asynchornous - i.e., the app will see user as `null` initially and after a second it will have a user object. So, populate your UI based on .`onAuthStateChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You method does not return a promise. So the solution is to call your logic in the callback.

```
myMethod() {
  const previousCards = this.state.cards;

  firebase.database().ref().child('app').child('cards')
    .orderByChild('uid').equalTo(this.state.uid)
    .once('value', snap => {
      snap.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        previousCards.push ({
          id: childSnapshot.key,
          cardDesc: childSnapshot.val().cardDesc,
          cardPreis: childSnapshot.val().cardPreis,
          cardHeading: childSnapshot.val().cardHeading,
          cardBewertung: childSnapshot.val().bewertung,
          cardImage: childSnapshot.val().imageUrl,
          standOrt: childSnapshot.val().ort,
          imageArr: childSnapshot.val().imageArr,
        })
        this.setState ({
          cards: previousCards,
        })
      })
    })
  }

componentWillMount(){
  let whenAuth = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
    const userProfile = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user){
      this.setState({
        authenticated: true,
        name : userProfile.displayName,
        email : userProfile.email,
        uid : userProfile.uid,
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        authenticated: false,
      })
      return <Redirect to="/"/>
    }

    // --> your function ends here
    this.myMethod();
  })
}
```

Comment: i tried but i think the wrong function get's called first... the function in componentWillMount has to be called and after it is finished, myMethod should me called.

Comment: Glad to help :)